# Optimal Number of Entries in Contest of Skill

Tags: probability, decision-theory

**Objective:**  I'm looking for the optimal number of unique entries in a contest of skill with monetary prizes.

**Description:**  The contests vary from as little as 20 entries up to 10,000+ entries.  You can enter an unlimited amount of entries.  Within each entry, there are 9 slots that can be filled with variables.  Each slot has a unique set of variables that cannot be used in any other slot.  The unique variables for each slot may number from about 2-30 depending on the contest.  Once you enter your chosen variables in the slots, the variables score points based upon real-life events.  Some slots traditionally score many more points than other slots.  The entry with the highest amount of points wins.  Prize money is split in the event of a tie score.

**Assumptions:** I am an above average player.  When facing similar competition, assume I can win 57% of the time (if playing in a fifty/fifty contest where half of the entrants win prize money).  The contest has exactly 10,055 entries.  The entry fee is $2.  The prize distribution is detailed as follows (minus 10.5% entry fee going to contest organizers):

**Prizes:**

**1st:** $2,000;
**2nd:** 1,200;
**3rd:** 800;
**4th:** 500;
**5th:** 350;
**6th:** 300;
**7th:** 250;
**8th:** 200;
**9th:** 180;
**10th**: 160;
**11th:** 150;
**12th:** 140;
**13th:** 130;
**14th:** 120;
**15th:** 110;
**16th:** 100;
**17th - 18th:** 90;
**19th - 20th:** 80;
**21st - 22nd:** 70;
**23rd - 25th:** 60;
**26th - 28th:** 50;
**29th - 35th:** 40;
**36th - 50th:** 30;
**51st - 60th:** 20;
**61st - 75th:** 18;
**76th - 100th:** 16;
**101st - 200th:** 14;
**201st - 400th:** 12;
**401st - 600th:** 10;
**601st - 800th:** 8;
**801st - 1050th:** 6

**Discussion:** I have an above average understanding of probability (but that's not really saying much), so I've gotten as far as running a simulation (the paper and pencil kine) with 10 entries and a 10 dollar entry fee (1st-$50, 2nd-30, 3rd-20).  Internet research suggests, and my paper simulations concur, that using 2 or more of the exact same entries will always result in a negative expected value (EV).

I then tried to run the simulation with two different entries.  There seem to be 44 unique possibilities. I added up the prize money; then, I multiplied by 1/44.  I took this answer then subtracted the $20 in entry fees.  The result was an expected value of 45 cents.  Is this correct?

Assuming my math is correct, I have no clue how to apply it to the contests with a much higher number of entries to find the optimal number of unique entries I should submit.  I don't really know how to translate my assumed 57% success rate in one contest to another contest.  I also don't know if it's best to have completely unique entries or just slightly unique entries (it seems that I should diversify my entries and make them as unique as possible while still maximizing points scored).

Any help, guidance, or tips are very much appreciated.  Have a great day.

P.S. If you know the contests I'm talking about, please don't refer to them by name.

P.S.S. I wasn't sure whether to post this question here or on the math.stackexchange